# Как сделать такую анимацию при скроле страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста с анимацией блока будомат. Я хочу добиться того, чтобы когда пользователь дойдет до секции offer (2ая секция) запускался скрипт (можно на ваниле или jquery) который соединит 3 части будомата вплотную, при этом, при скроле, сам будет опускаться вниз, примерно до конца своей родительской секции. Большое спасибо за помощь.

https://jsfiddle.net/dmitriyPHC/zdyqofug/37/

````
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="header__title">hello ХАБР</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section class="offer">
     <div class="container">
     <h2 class="offer__title">
          Второй заголовок
        </h2>
      <div class="budomat">
        <div class="budomat__item budomat__item--first"></div>
        <div class="budomat__item budomat__item--middle"></div>
        <div class="budomat__item budomat__item--last"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section> ```
````

Comment: на тостере не помогли а здесь щас из за скуки за пять сек сделают

Comment: @Sevastopol'  будомат это имя блока в html

Comment: @Sevastopol Будомат - это спортивное покрытие, он состоит из 3-х слоев (в песочнице это красный, черный и синий) изначально они расположены на расстоянии друг от друга, но когда пользователь доходит до секции где он расположен и начинает скролить дальше,  слои  должны встать друг к другу( как в песочнице выгдяlит .budomat--complete

Comment: @Sevastopol'  я имел ввиду, что при скроле блок .budomat ( у него pos. relative и 3 цветных блока позицианируются он него ) опустится вниз скажем на 300px, может это паралакс называется,я не в курсе. Причем вся эта анимация работала только при скроле, а не делалась автоматически когда пользователь доскролит до 2 секции.